# Bash shell - shorter way to remove last characters from the file name

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell

I can append a string to a filename without having to enter the repeating part of the command twice:

```
mv foo{,_bar}
```

And this renames my `foo` into `foo_bar` .

Is there a way to do the opposite - remove the `_bar` from `foo_bar` filename without having to enter the same again?
That is to say - not doing something like:

```
mv long/path/to/foo_bar long/path/to/foo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bash, you can use parameter expansion:

```
path=/long/path/to/foo_bar
mv "$path" "${path%_bar}"  # Remove the pattern from the end of the value.
```

For literal string, you can just switch the order of the elements in the curlies:

```
mv long/path/to/foo{_bar,}
```